# PostgreSQL loop with random inserts

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, postgresql

I have a table in db:

```
CREATE TABLE operation ( <br>
    id     integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('seq_operation'),( <br>
    phone_number     varchar(30),( <br>
    age     integer,( <br>
    gender     char(1),( <br>
    isActive     boolean,( <br>
    date_of_surgery     timestamp,( <br>
);
```

I need to insert 10000 rows with random data. How can I make such INSERT statement? Im fresh with this stuff and trying to figure it out with other answers for similiar question here, but cant find easy understandable one for me.

I would really appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Max

Comment: many ways to do it. Loop for 10000, in the loop make a dummy object(operation) with data then single insert with JDBC. Thats it. Or make 10000 objects then loop to insert those!

Comment: use some mock dite sites like: https://www.mockaroo.com/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I usually use something like this is psql:

```
INSERT INTO table (values, to, fill) 
SELECT random(), random(), random() from generate_series(1,10000);
```

In your case, this will be:

```
INSERT INTO operation ( 
  phone_number,
  age,
  gender,
  isActive,
  date_of_surgery
) SELECT 
  'some-phone-' || round(random()*1000), -- for text
  round(random()*70), -- for integer
  (ARRAY['f','m'])[round(random())+1], -- for char/enum
  (ARRAY[false,true])[round(random())+1], -- for boolean
  now() + round(random()*1000) * '1 second'::interval -- for timestamps
FROM generate_series(1,10000);
```

A bit more explanation.

- [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) will provide you the loop, also you can access
  the values it generates. Those are not needed now.
- `'text' || round(random()*1000)` can generate 'text-1212'-like unique
  strings.
- `round(random()*70)` - you need to round, because random() returns a
  floting point value between 0 and 1.
- `(ARRAY['f','m'])[round(random())+1]` - for enum and alike, build an
  array and generate a random index for it
- `now() + round(random()*1000) * '1 second'::interval` - get a baseline
  date and add random time [intervals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html).

([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ea665/1))

Comment: Thanks man you are the best! Two more question if u don't mind, from your query I get date format like: 2017-08-07T12:30:37.400894Z, what if I only want: 2017-08-07T12:30:37?
And you said I can access the values that generate_series generates. How can i do it?

Comment: You can use `date_trunc` for truncate a timestamp to a given precision. If you assign an alias for generate_series, you can use that in your SELECT list. For example `SELECT a FROM generate_series(1,10) AS a;`